# MySQL query to unite multiple timestamp records into one

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I'm trying to make a query to significantly shorten employee badge stamping tables.

They have one record for each stamp, for example:

```
Badge   Date        Time    Type
430016  12/12/2016  09:34   In
430016  12/12/2016  13:02   Out
430016  12/12/2016  13:26   In
430016  12/12/2016  17:58   Out
430016  12/12/2016  18:01   In
430016  12/12/2016  19:02   Out
```

I need a mysql query to put it all in one record i.e.

```
Badge    Date        In1    Out1    In2     Out2    In3    Out3
0430016  2/12/2016   09:34  13:02   13:26   17:58   18:01  19:02
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` will help you here.

Comment: Are you asking for exactly three pairs of in/out columns in the result of the query, or do you want it to vary depending on how many in/out records there are for each badge?

Comment: If there are less stamps than 4 the extra field can be empty, what matters is that for each person I can have one record with all stamps rather than multiple ones, through a mysql query

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a Pivot Table.  It turns rows into columns.

Here is a tutorial http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

Also here is another post on stackoverflow that is very similar
[MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT Badge, Date, GROUP_CONCAT(TIME ORDER BY TIME SEPARATOR ',') as times, 
GROUP_CONCAT(TYPE ORDER BY TIME SEPARATOR ',') as types
    FROM peoples_hobbies GROUP BY Badge
```

You can get the result by string manipulation with separator ','.